# Parsing alternative XML literals in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I'm working in Scala and need to distinguish between XML messages that represent either success or failure.  The information I've found provides lots of insight into pulling apart a known XML fragment but not where you're unsure of which fragment you have.

Here are the two possible messages:

```
val success = XML.loadString("""<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
                <cas:authenticationSuccess>
                   <cas:user>bwbecker</cas:user>
                </cas:authenticationSuccess>
              </cas:serviceResponse>""")

val failure = XML.loadString("""<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
                <cas:authenticationFailure code='INVALID_REQUEST'>
                  &#039;service&#039; and &#039;ticket&#039; parameters are both required
                </cas:authenticationFailure>
              </cas:serviceResponse>""")
```

The following code does what I want (I'll eventually return an Either of case classes, but this is fine for playing...):

```
def parse(response: NodeSeq):Either[String, String] = {

(response \ "authenticationSuccess").headOption
  .flatMap(succ => (succ \ "user").headOption)
  .map(usr => Right(usr.text))
  .getOrElse((response \ "authenticationFailure").headOption
    .map{fail => 
        val code = fail \ "@code"
        val msg = fail.text
        Left(s"Failure: ${code} ${msg}")
    }
    .getOrElse(Left("Really Botched"))
  )
}
```

However, I find this really hard to code and read.  Is there a better way?  What if I had five different messages to distinguish?

I tried matchers, but got discouraged with the arcane syntax for XML (the cas: namespace seems to complicate things).

Any guidance for improving my code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm going to go with:

```
def parse(response: NodeSeq):Either[String, String] = {
    response \\ "user" match {
        case ns if !ns.isEmpty => Right(ns.text)
        case ns => response \\ "authenticationFailure" match {
            case ns if !ns.isEmpty => 
                val code = ns \ "@code"
                val msg = ns.text.trim
                Left(s"Failure: ${code} ${msg}")
            case ns => Left("Unexpected response from CAS: " + response.toString)
        }
    }
}
```

It uses \ to search through the tree rather than \ that my original solution used (that same technique could also simplify my original solution).  It also uses a match statement, obviously.  I think the match statement makes the result more readable and easier to develop than the original solution.  But maybe I'm just showing my imperative roots!

Comment: Do you really need to return an Either[]? If it were me I would return an Option[String] if authenticated, otherwise None.